# change the 7 segment counter display

Tags: c

I designed a reaction game using my Arduino and an ETS-7000 device and I had a little proble.

The game idea is that there will be two players playing against each other and I used three LED's which they are on the ETS-7000 already.

The two 7 segments will start on 9 and 9 and when the third LED blinks the two players should press the swithces.

The slower player will reduce 1 point and for that his 7 segment will 8 and the game will continue like till some reaches 0 and loses.

My proble is that I did every thing correct but instead of the slower player reduce 1 point on his 7 segment, the faster player does.

I need a help so I adjust the code to be in the oppisite way

P.S. I used a BCD coding for the 7 segment

```
  int SW2 = 3; //try
  int SW1 = 4;
  int LED0 = A0;
  int LED1 = 12;
  int LED2 = 13;
 // int fault = 0;
  //long wait = 0;
  //long now = 0;
  void setup(){
   pinMode(A5, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(A4, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(LED0, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(SW1, INPUT);
   pinMode(SW2, INPUT);
  //Initializing components
   randomSeed(analogRead(1));
 }
void loop(){
reset:
  int n=9, x=9;
                           digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
                            digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(9, LOW);
               digitalWrite(10, LOW);
               digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
  do{
      digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
  //Wait for a random period of time, between 3 seconds
 //And 6 seconds. Get ready!
 delay(random(500,8000));
  digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  //Swing your swords as fast as you can, the faster one 
 //will be returned by getWinner()
 int winner=getWinner();
  //The yellow led by side of the winner will light up
 if(winner==1){
   if (n==1)
            {
             digitalWrite(A5, LOW);
             digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
             digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
             digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             delay(5000);
             break;  
            } 
   else
   {n=n-1;}
  }else{ if (x==1)
           {
             digitalWrite(8, LOW);
             digitalWrite(9, LOW);
             digitalWrite(10, LOW);
             digitalWrite(11, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
             delay(100);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
             delay(5000);
             break;
             }
   else { x=x-1;}
 }
             if (n==0){
               digitalWrite(A5, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
            } else if (n==1){
               digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
            } else if (n==2){
               digitalWrite(A5, LOW );
               digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
           } else if (n==3){
               digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
           } else if (n==4){ 
               digitalWrite(A5, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
           } else if (n==5){
               digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
           } else if (n==6) {
               digitalWrite(A5, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
           } else if (n==7){ 
               digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A4, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
           } else if (n==8){
               digitalWrite(A5, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
           } else if (n==9){
               digitalWrite(A5, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(A4, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
               digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
            }
                  if (x==0){
               digitalWrite(8, LOW);
               digitalWrite(9, LOW);
               digitalWrite(10, LOW);
               digitalWrite(11, LOW);
           } else if (x==1){
               digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(9, LOW);
               digitalWrite(10, LOW);
               digitalWrite(11, LOW);
            } else if (x==2){
               digitalWrite(8, LOW );
               digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(10, LOW);
               digitalWrite(11, LOW);
            } else if (x==3){
               digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
               digitalWrite(10, LOW);
               digitalWrite(11, LOW);
            } else if (x==4){ 
                digitalWrite(8, LOW);
                digitalWrite(9, LOW);
                digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(11, LOW);
             } else if (x==5){
                digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(9, LOW);
                digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(11, LOW);
             } else if (x==6) {
                digitalWrite(8, LOW);
                 digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(11, LOW);
             } else if (x==7){ 
                digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(11, LOW);
              } else if (x==8){
                digitalWrite(8, LOW);
                digitalWrite(9, LOW);
                digitalWrite(10, LOW);
                digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
              } else if (x==9) {
                digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(9, LOW);
                digitalWrite(10, LOW);
                digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
              }
             digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
             digitalWrite(LED2, LOW); 
 delay(2000);
  } while(true);
         goto reset;
  }
 //The function below waits for either of the tilter
//switch to be swang. The first one to swing
//will be returned by its number
int getWinner(){
  do{
    if(digitalRead(SW1)==HIGH){
      return 1;
    }else if(digitalRead(SW2)==HIGH){
      return 2;
    }
  }while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a corrected version in consecutive fragments.

First, the pin numbers should be defined at the top and be given meaningful names. It also makes the code vastly simpler if everything is indexed by player number.

```
#define PLAYER1 0
#define PLAYER2 1

const int ALERT_LED = 12;   

// Pins of the BCD display for both players, most significant bit first
const int PLAYER_DISPLAY[2][4] = {
    { A2, A3, A4, A5 },
    { 11, 10, 9, 8 }
};

const int PLAYER_LED[2] = { A0, 13 };
const int PLAYER_SWITCH[2] = {4, 3 };
```

Functions are your friends. We will regroup output functionality here.

```
void set_display (int player, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        digitalWrite (PLAYER_DISPLAY[player][3 - i], value & (1 << i));
    }
}

void blink_led (int pin)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        digitalWrite (pin, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite (pin, LOW);
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

We do the same for input functionality.

```
// return the number of the first player to press its switch
int get_winner ()
{
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (digitalRead(PLAYER_SWITCH[i]) == HIGH) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We setup the pins direction.

```
void setup ()
{
    // set pins direction and ensure the leds are off
    pinMode (ALERT_LED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite (ALERT_LED, LOW);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             pinMode (PLAYER_DISPLAY[i][j], OUTPUT);
        }
        pinMode (PLAYER_LED[i], OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite (PLAYER_LED[i], LOW);
        pinMode (PLAYER_SWITCH[i], INPUT);
    }

   // initialize random number generator    
   randomSeed(analogRead(1));
}
```

Now, thanks to our preparatory work, the main loop is simpler and its logic clearly apparent, making it easier to change and errors easier to spot.

```
void loop()
{
    int score[2] = { 9, 9 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        set_display (i, score[i]);
    }

    while (true) {
        // turn on the leds in sequence
        digitalWrite(PLAYER_LED[PLAYER1], HIGH);
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(PLAYER_LED[PLAYER2], HIGH);
        delay(random(500,8000));
        digitalWrite(ALERT_LED, HIGH);

        // get winner
        int winner = get_winner();
        int loser = (winner == PLAYER1) ? PLAYER2 : PLAYER1;

        // update score
        score[loser]--;
        set_display (loser, score[loser]);

        // turn the leds off
        digitalWrite(PLAYER_LED[PLAYER1], LOW);
        digitalWrite(PLAYER_LED[PLAYER2], LOW);
        digitalWrite(ALERT_LED, LOW);

        // if the game is over, blink the winner's led and restart
        if (score[loser] == 0) {
             blink_led (PLAYER_LED[winner]);
             delay(5000);
             break;  
        }

        delay(2000);
  }
}
```

I hope you learn from these principles. It's ok if you don't understand everything (in particular the working of set_display()).

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to read exactly what's going on here, but it sounds like you're suffering from a logic inversion.

Basically, your program should doing this:

1. Check the winner, return the winner number (presumably 0 or 1)
2. If winner user == 1, check and reduce the number of user 0
3. Else, check and reduce the number of user 1
4. Write out the new numbers

What your program is *actually* doing is either:

1. Returning the wrong number for the winner
2. Modifying the number of the wrong user - that is to say, if winner
   number == 1, it should decrement **x** rather than *n*.

There's a simple way to make your program work - if this is the only issue - and that's change the logic of

```
if( winner == 1 )
```

to

```
if( winner != 1 )
```

This will invert the logic and resolve the issue. HOWEVER. Be aware that this may just be a case of "two wrongs make a right". If your code is miscalculating the winner, this will be exactly that and you'd be better off fixing that rather than reversing the error later. It's also worth bearing in mind that if you ever want to extend this to 3 or more players, using the != logic now will mean you'll have to rewrite it later.

If the calculation of the winner is correct, then your other option to correct it is to change around the number that is altered, so in the first if/else section on winner == 1, swap every instance of x with n and vice versa. You may also need to swap around the instances of LEDs 9-11 and A2-A5, depending on how that's set up. It's hard to tell because of the lack of any comments re: what these LEDs actually represent :)